# Is it safe to install and use app from ”untrusted developer“?

Tags: ios, applications, security

Cryptocurrency wallet bter.com/mobileapp are asking me to install its app directly from corporate repository. It's firs time when I'm able to see such thing.

Is it safe to work with this app? Or it can possibly steal some of my data because of ”mistrust“?

[image: Screenshot of the popup window]

P.S.: I know how to avoid this popup window and start working. The only thing that I want to specify is how safe to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, no, it is not safe as the pop-up states. As you don't know where the app comes from and it has not been checked by Apple's reviewers.

You'd need to install the app developers' certificate to install this app. That certificate could be misused to extract data/control phone/misuse information. Companies often use their own certificates via mobile device management to do such things. Like wiping a stolen phone or blocking the user after leaving the company.

### Further Explained

The warning is generated to protect users to install apps from untrusted (not validated, unknown) developers. This mostly occurs on apps being downloaded outside of given app-stores.

In this case (I don't know the app) you really want to lookup the developers site and references.

Maybe it's an open source project. Open Source projects produce this warning but in many cases this warning can be ignored as the project has been reviewed by a bunch of users stating it is safe to install. Still: Caution!.

A search shows [a company with the same name is already](https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/youland-information-technology-shanghai-co-ltd/id997654116) in the iOS App Store. Though, I don't know whether it's the same company. And there seems to be a reason why the app is not listed in the app store.